# Pushbutton in a particular cell of a tableview when hovering

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, delegates, qtableview

I am currently developing an app using Qt's MVC approach. I have a StandardItemModel which i use to populate the tableview. My tableview has 2 columns. In the first column I obtain the data from the model. Now in the second column I want to show a pushbutton when the user hovers the first column.

I want the button to be row specific. i.e., when the user hovers over the cell(0,0), the pushbutton is shown in the (0,1) cell. Similarly I want to do it for all the rows in my tableview.

As far as i know, there are two approaches, **Delegates & setIndexWidget.** 
I tried using QStyledItemDelgate and was not successful. setIndexWidget leads to performance issues as my tableview has a large data set.

Any code sample or idea of how to go about it would be really helpful.

Comment: what do you need the push buttons for ? editing ?

Comment: @basslo: I need it to perform some functionality. When the pushbutton is clicked, the row should be removed from the Table.